# Dockerized streamlit app based on poetry - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Lib'

Tags: python, docker

I build the following docker image. Currently i use the same versions of poetry and python like on my dev system.

```
FROM python:3.8.8

EXPOSE 8501

ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.1.7

RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}

RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

# Install dependencies
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-dev --no-ansi

CMD ["poetry", "run", "streamlit", "run", "src/projecthours/app.py"]
```

For some reason the python standard libary is missing.
How to fix this error? I wonder why this libary is missing?

> from Lib import calendar, datetime, difflib
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Lib'

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to just use the imports directly.

```
import datetime
import calendar
import difflib
```

Instead of `from Lib import datetime,...`